# How to display a range of date values from MYSQL into a table form in php with pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, html, pagination

I do not know which part of my codes is wrong.

This is what I need,

I need to search a range of dates of records and display onto a table in php page.

Start: (text field)
End : (text field)
(submit button)

When i only key in start text field area, i'm able to retrieve the information with what I requested and pagination is ok.

Once i keyed in 2 text fields. My restest.php page manage to display The first 50 values on a table with my page number.

For example: 
Date 1 = 07/06/2015
Date 2 = 07/27/2015

I supposed to have 142 rows limit 50.
My page display a table of 50 rows with 3 numbers of page.

```
1 2 3
```

But once i clicked page 2 or next or other pages
My page will only display the results of only my Date 1 which have 80 records
and 2 pages.

```
1 2
```

### This is my codes for index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of your search engine</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='restest.php' method='GET'>
<center>
<h1>My Search Engine</h1>
<input type='text' size='90' name='search'></br></br>
<input type='text' size='90' name='end'></br></br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search source code' ></br></br></br>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my codes for restest.php

```
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$s = $_GET ['search']; 
$e = $_GET ['end'];

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $s, $e);

$x = "";
$construct = "";  

$constructs ="SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Date >='".$s."' AND Date <= '".$e."' ";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
echo $foundnum;

$per_page = 50;
$start = isset($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start']: '';
$max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
if(!$start)
$start=0; 

$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Date >= '".$s."' AND Date <= '".$e."'  ");


    echo "<table id=wTable>";
    echo "<table id=hTable style=width:800px; border=1px;>
    <tr style=background-color:black;color:yellow;font-size:18px;>
    <td style=width:200px>Username</th>
    <td style=width:175px>Date</th>
    <td style=width:225px>a</th>
    <td style=width:200px>b</th>
    </tr>";

    echo "</table>";
    echo "<div id ='test' style=width:820px;height:200px;overflow:auto;>";
    echo "<table id=dTable width=800px border=1px>";  

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
    echo "<tr style=color:black;background-color:grey;font-size:13px;>";
    echo "<td style=width:200px>" . $row['Username'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style=width:175px >" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style=width:225px>" . $row['a'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style=width:200px>" . $row['b'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";  
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";



//Pagination Starts
echo "<center>";

$prev = $start - $per_page;
$next = $start + $per_page;

$adjacents = 3;
$last = $max_pages - 1;

if($max_pages > 1)
{   
//previous button
if (!($start<=0)) 
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$prev'>Prev</a> ";    

//pages 
if ($max_pages < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
{
$i = 0;   
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
}  
$i = $i + $per_page;                 
}
}
elseif($max_pages > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
{
//close to beginning; only hide later pages
if(($start/$per_page) < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
{
$i = 0;
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
} 
$i = $i + $per_page;                                       
}

}
//in middle; hide some front and some back
elseif($max_pages - ($adjacents * 2) > ($start / $per_page) && ($start / $per_page) > ($adjacents * 2))
{
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=0'>1</a> ";
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";

$i = $start;                 
for ($counter = ($start/$per_page)+1; $counter < ($start / $per_page) + $adjacents + 2; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";
}   
$i = $i + $per_page;                
}

}
//close to end; only hide early pages
else
{
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=0'>1</a> ";
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$per_page'>2</a> .... ";

$i = $start;                
for ($counter = ($start / $per_page) + 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++)
{
if ($i == $start){
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'><b>$counter</b></a> ";
}
else {
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$i'>$counter</a> ";   
} 
$i = $i + $per_page;              
}
}
}

//next button
if (!($start >=$foundnum-$per_page))
echo " <a href='restest.php?search=$s&submit=Search&start=$next'>Next</a> ";    
}   
echo "</center>";
```

Comment: And I used GET method form from my previous page

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your code you are relying on an old, insecure and no longer available feature of PHP called [register globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). With register globals enabled, PHP would automatically inject all GET and POST data (among others) as variables, leading to unpredictable and insecure results in code.

What you should do instead, is to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` directly, depending on the type of data you expect. In your case, you should use $_GET['start'] to get the start parameter sent by your script. Or even better, do some input validation on it as well. For example:

```
$start = 0;
if (!empty($_GET['start']) && intval($_GET['start']) > 0) {
    $start = intval($_GET['start']);
}
```

For more information on processing GET and POST-parameters, please check [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the heads up! Sorry i'm new to php I don't really get what you mean. But my index.php I actually had a <form method = "POST" action = "restest.php"> and at my restest page i actually used $s = $_GET['start']; to retrieve my values from previous page

Comment: In short: to access the start parameter from the url (or other url/GET-parameters), you have to use $_GET['start'], not $start. If you are looking for a POST-parameter, use $_POST. Check http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php for more information.

Comment: I get what you mean :) $start isn't what i'm calling from the previous page parameter.  Before my parameter codes I actually declared this

$s = $_GET ['search']; 
$e = $_GET ['end'];

search and end is my previous page textfields name. 

Thanks!

Anyway i've updated my question could you help me review it again please? Because I've stuck in this pagination for 3 days for my major project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I still do not see any code in your example that actually populates $start.

Comment: Hi sorry i've updated my question and copy and paste my 2 pages codes. I didn't copy in my database connection